# Excel file has "0" bytes

Tags: 7, webforms

I have a Drupal 7 webform, which allows me to download the submissions as a .xlsx. I am able to download the submission forms but all the .xlsx files has 0 bytes. Somehow it works in staging site but it doesn't work in Development and Production. I use Acquia Server for staging and production; for development I use Acquia Dev Desktop. I have tried a few things such as:

1. I changed my .htaccess memory settings
2. I added some of the patches from drupal.org
3. I double checked the configurations of File System's Public file system path and Temporary directory, staging and production settings are identical

Has anyone encountered the same issue before that can lead me for solution? I have spent quite 1 week for this.

Comment: Try to locate where the files should be uploaded, and give permission 0777 to that folder.

Comment: No luck with that.